# Jquery Data Table Filter Custom Sorting onload?

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am Using Data table jQuery plugin for filtring my data.

> this is my sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM project_task where emp_id ='$empid' AND task_type ='random' ORDER BY task_id DESC";
```

> code of table is

```
<table id="example" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background: #064769;color: #FFF;">
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Task</th>
                    <th > Description </th>
                    <th> Hours </th>
                    <th> Date </th>
                    <th> Rating </th>    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
         <tr>
            <td> <?php  echo $row["task_id"] ?></td>
            <td> <?php  echo $row["task"] ?></td>
            <td>  <?php echo $row["description"]; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php  echo $row["hours"]; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php  echo $row["submit_date"];?></td>
            <td> <?php  echo $row["submit_date"];?></td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

> as per I am Using DESC in sql query. task has been shown in DESC order but not when i remove data table plugin it is working fine. I think there is filter which is working on page load. I was using cdn now i installed it into local i am finding that there is any function which is sorting it but i have not pro in JS if you know how to solve it please tell me.

I am attaching screen shot also: which is showing tasks are sorted automatically ASC order.

[image: please check image here]

> this is my jQuery function for data table:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();          
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your jquery code you have pass arguments like:

```
              $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#example').DataTable( {
                            "paging":   true,
                            "ordering": false,
                            "info":     true
                    } );
              });
```

> you can also see documentation for the more clarity .

Comment: ok but it takes time but i will try otherwise please help me.

Comment: I did not got it

Comment: yes go to documentation here: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html